# Is there a Cake equivalent for Python?

Tags: python, makefile, build-automation

I've raked through a lot of "make for Python" projects, but I can't find any with the simplicity of a [cake file](https://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script/wiki/%5BHowTo%5D-Compiling-and-Setting-Up-Build-Tools). What I'm looking for is a Python equivalent that will let me:

1. Keep the build commands in a single file in my project root
2. Define each task as a simple function with a description that will automatically be displayed when the "make" file is run without arguments
3. Import my Python modules

I'm picturing something like this:

```
from pymake import task, main

@task('reset_tables', 'Drop and recreate all MySQL tables')
def reset_tables():
    # ...

@task('build_stylus', 'Build the stylus files to public/css/*')
def build_stylus():
    from myproject import stylus_builder
    # ...

@task('build_cscript', 'Build the coffee-script files to public/js/*')
def build_cscript():
    # ...

@task('build', 'Build everything buildable')
def build():
    build_cscript()
    build_stylus()

# etc...

# Function that parses command line args etc...
main()
```

I've searched and searched but found nothing like it. If it doesn't exist, I will make it myself and probably answer this question with it.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: See http://farmdev.com/thoughts/46/the-python-make-tool/; there are plenty of options.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Yes there are plenty of make tool options, but they are all either dead or overly complicated and complex. I really don't need anything more than the example I provided, and I still haven't found a build tool for Python that even has the option of being that simple

Comment: Don't look at me then; I use zc.buildout (daily) for all my deployment tasks. Probably not the same use-case as to what you are looking for though.

Comment: related: [paver](http://paver.github.com/paver/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It’s not that hard to build a simple solution yourself:

```
import sys

tasks = {}
def task (f):
    tasks[f.__name__] = f
    return f

def showHelp ():
    print('Available tasks:')
    for name, task in tasks.items():
        print('  {0}: {1}'.format(name, task.__doc__))

def main ():
    if len(sys.argv) < 2 or sys.argv[1] not in tasks:
        showHelp()
        return

    print('Executing task {0}.'.format(sys.argv[1]))
    tasks[sys.argv[1]]()
```

And then a small sample:

```
from pymake import task, main

@task
def print_foo():
    '''Prints foo'''
    print('foo')

@task
def print_hello_world():
    '''Prints hello world'''
    print('Hello World!')

@task
def print_both():
    '''Prints both'''
    print_foo()
    print_hello_world()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

And what it looks like when used:

```
> .\test.py
Available tasks:
  print_hello_world: Prints hello world
  print_foo: Prints foo
  print_both: Prints both
> .\test.py print_hello_world
Executing task print_hello_world.
Hello World!
```

Comment: I was referring to the subcommand part of argparse. Having a nice way of using decorators to define subcommands is what I had in mind.

Comment: +1 - Nice answer, and I've already made a solution like this for my current project :-) I was wondering if a similar solution already existed though, presumably with a bit more functionality, before I went through the trouble of turning mine into a reusable package. Nice touch with using the functions' names and doc-strings though!

Comment: I am declaring this the correct answer. This is because the *fabric* library is actually pretty huge, not just a small build tool as I was looking for

Answer (score 3):

Have you looked into using [fabric](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.4.3/index.html)?

To implement your example using it, you'd just need to add this to a file named `fabfile.py`:

```
def reset_tables():
    ''' Drop and recreate all MySQL tables '''
    # ...

def build_stylus():
    ''' Build the stylus files to public/css/ '''
    from myproject import stylus_builder
    # ...

def build_cscript():
    ''' Build the coffee-script files to public/js/* '''
    # ...

def build():
    ''' Build everything buildable '''
    build_cscript()
    build_stylus()
```

Then you just need to run `fab build` to build.  And you can run `fab -l` to see the avaliable commands along with their descriptions.

Guess it's also worth mentioning that fabric provides some other functionality that you may (or may not) find useful.  Amongst other things it's got some functions to help with deploying files to remote servers and some others that allow you to run remote commands through ssh.  Since it looks like you're developing a web-based project you may find this useful for creating deployment scripts or similar.

Answer (score 2):

Funny, there's a Python build tool called Cake that uses nearly the same syntax as you example. See it [here](https://github.com/alexcepoi/cake).

Comment: Wow, that's... incredibly confusing :S

Answer (score 0):

I would just create a standard Makefile rather than find something language-specific. In a few of my projects, `make db`, `make test`, etc. map to scripts that are written in Python, but could just as easily be in any language whose scripts are executable from the command line.

Comment: I voted this answer *not useful* because it doesn't address the #1 concern in my question: Keeping all the build code in one file

Comment: Fair enough. Curious as to your motive behind wanting a single file, but if it's a priority, it's a priority. Fabric is indeed a good option for such a thing.